# iOS10 A http request becomes https request, but some not

Tags: ios

Yesterday, I found a bug when using my App, when I try to download a AGPS file and update my cycling computer for locate faster. The AGPS cound not be download.

- AGPS file url is: http://alp.u-blox.com/current_14d.alp
- iOS system version : iOS 10.3.2
- Network: WIFI and mobile network 4G

Steps below is what I do to check the bug.

1. Check the AGPS file on Safari(on my Macbook pro), it can be download successfully.
2. Open the AGPS file url in Chrome, but can NOT download, it shows me:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from alp.u-blox.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
>
> Automatically send some system information and page content to Google to help detect dangerous apps and sites. Privacy policy

3. Open the AGPS URL on my Android phone browser, download file success.
4. Open the AGPS URL on my iPhone Safari, can not open the web page.

Then I capture the app request using Charles, it shows me the url really request is changed to :

```
https://alp.u-blox.com/current_14d.alp
-- http changed to https
```

Someone say the problem is because of the iOS10 force all http request using https. So I add some settings on my Info.plist like this.

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<key>sina.com.cn</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
    <string>TLSv1.0</string>
    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

or like this

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<key>twitter.com</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Then re-capture the request, both are not working.

Network request Code as below:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPSessionManager *sessionManager;

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.sessionManager
                                          downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                                          progress:^(NSProgress *_Nonnull downloadProgress) {
                                              if (progressBlock) {
                                                  progressBlock((int64_t)downloadProgress.completedUnitCount, downloadProgress.totalUnitCount);
                                              }
                                          }
                                          destination:^NSURL *_Nonnull (NSURL *_Nonnull targetPath, NSURLResponse *_Nonnull response) {
                                              NSString *otaFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", kOTA_FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD_DIR, [response suggestedFilename]];
                                              return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:otaFilePath];
                                          }
                                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *_Nonnull response, NSURL *_Nullable filePath, NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                  xLog_error(@"[Error] 下载固件失败, Error Message: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                  completeHandler(NO, nil);
                                              } else {
                                                  completeHandler(YES, filePath.path);
                                              }
                                          }];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Request by the NSURLSession also not working.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                       @"postman-token": @"aa15f00a-bc58-082a-c8e3-e636537b7fa7" };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"http://alp.u-blox.com/current_14d.alp"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                               timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, 
NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                            if (error) {
                                                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                            } else {
                                                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                            }
                                        }];
[dataTask resume];
```

**My question**

1. Does iOS10 change the url from http to https? or changed by the web server?
2. Why the url can be open by Safari (on PC) and can NOT opened on Safari(on iPhone)?
3. Why it can be opened on Android?

**More what I do**

I get the file from the server and upload it to a file host server: https://www.qiniu.com/, the copy the file address like this:

`http://okzqhpqwj.bkt.clouddn.com/current_14d.alp`

Put the url into the code, everything is good and the request is not changed to https. Why??!!

Any help is grateful, thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, how to send a http request using iOS10...

Comment: The forwarding of HTTP to HTTPS is done by web server, not really related to the App itself.  Also, why tag Android? Last, please show us the download code you wrote.

Comment: Thank you, Raptor. I also test the Android version app,  request the same url and works fine. Android version 7.0. This is also a question what I cann't understand, If same url, why Android can visit, but iOS10.0 can NOT. Is the Android security level different?

Comment: I shall explain this `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` really does. Since iOS 9, Apps without `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` or explicitly set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `false` (default value) will block the following URLs:

1. Insecure HTTP connection (i.e. http://)
2. HTTPS with TLS version < v1.2

Do not set it to `true` in Production environment, and App review will ask for justification for setting it to `true`. Allow only necessary domains with `NSExceptionDomains`.

HTTPS with invalid certificate will also be blocked by `AFNetworking` by default. To workaround with this issue, you **should** use a valid certificate (it's important to keep all certificates valid & secure, always), or use the following codes at the header of your file:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_
#endif
```

Related Github commit [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/204)

---

For your questions, here are the answers:

1. Does iOS10 change the url from http to https? or changed by the web server?

> It's done by web server, not the App itself.

2. Why the url can be open by Safari (on PC) and can NOT opened on Safari(on iPhone)?

> It seems that it checks the user agent. Please double check by changing the User Agent and retry (Hint: easiest way is to use HTTP client Chrome extension / Firefox Addon to test)

3. Why it can be opened on Android?

> Same answer as Question 2

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I use the AFNetworking in the release version, I still can not get the http resource, right? I also try to use NSURLSession download the file, not using AFNetworking, but still not working.

Comment: For production environment (a.k.a. release version), you have to set allowed domains using `NSExceptionDomains` no matter you use `AFNetworking` or not. Your problem is, the SSL certificate is invalid. Ask the web admin to use a valid certificate.

Comment: I need to ask the web admin of http://alp.u-blox.com, I don't think the out network problem. Because even I use the mobile network, I still can not access the file resource on http://alp.u-blox.com. If the web admin of http://alp.u-blox.com do not update a valid certificate, Is there any other way to access the resource I can use?

Comment: I changed nothing, but the problem gone today. Now, everything works fine. But I really did NOT do anything.

Comment: Maybe they updated the certificate. You can use this tool to check: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: Yes, maybe. Thank you so much.